# Spring Batch auto generated error Logging File not having timestamp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-logging

There are errors on start-up of spring batch which are getting logged into default error logging file (filename : project_name.err.log)but does not have timestamp to understand when the errors occurred .

We have the logging implementation in our project in the file specified in logback-spring.xml has the timestamp .

But this file (filename : project_name.err.log) is getting auto generated by spring batch . Can any one please help / suggest  to append the timestamp in this auto generated log file .

I am expecting this auto generated error log file to have a timestamp . But its not having the timestamp .
Tried to find out the logging configuration which will generate this file but did not found any .

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Spring Batch will log through the infrastructure presented with Spring Boot. So if it is logging somewhere else, that is how you configured things. Or you are totally bypassing logging for some reason, like not doig proper logging but writing to `System.err` yourself instead of using a logger.